# Fecha sin Hora en Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

las lineas de codigo de a continuación mandan a llamar la fecha de una tabla en mi base de dato, el tipo de dato es DATE... al mandarla a llamar le sumo un año y la muestro en un conbobox. mi problema es que la mostrarlo en un conbobox lo muestra con hora. ejemplo: "12/11/1997 12:00:00 a.m" y solo me interesa la fecha ya que la almacenare en otra tabla.

el codigo es el siguiente:

> ```
>         string fecha = null;
>
>         String ONFSeguro = "select DATEADD(year,1, InitVigencia) as fecha1 from DATOSSEGURO where Poliza= "+TBPoliza.Text;
>         SqlCommand OpFeSeguro = new SqlCommand();
>         OpFeSeguro.Connection = MenuInicio.conexion;
>         OpFeSeguro.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
>         OpFeSeguro.CommandText = ONFSeguro;
>
>         //Se lee el comando a ejecurar y el resultado se almacena temporalmente en un label llamado numero
>         //Se ejecuta el comando dentro del try por si ocurre un error se atrapa y se muestre atravez del catch
>         try
>         {
>             Leer = OpFeSeguro.ExecuteReader();
>             Leer.Read();
>             fecha = Leer["fecha1"].ToString();
>             NIVigencia.Text = fecha;
>             OpFeSeguro.Dispose();
>             OpFeSeguro = null;
>             Leer.Close();
>         }
>         catch (SqlException ex)
>         {
>             MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar darle un format en el `.ToString();`

```
fecha = Leer["fecha1"].ToString("yyyy/dd/mm");
```

Checa la siguiente [liga](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) para que veas más info acerca de las fechas.

Comment: Esa linea de codigo lo hice mostrando la fecha actual y funciono bien, lamentablemente como se muestra en el codigo hago una llamada que se almacena en una variable de tipo string... el ToString("yyyy/dd/mm"); por alguna manera me lo marca como error. todo el dia de hoy he estado intentando resolver eso pero no encuentro solucion.

Comment: bueno... después de tanto lo resolví de esta forma, por si alguien le interesa

fecha = Leer["fecha2"].ToString();
DateTime oDate2 = Convert.ToDateTime(fecha);
NFVigencia.Text = oDate2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas tantos pasos, puedes hacerlo directo si es un `DataReader`

```
NFVigencia.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Leer["fecha2"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

conviertes a `datetime` y luego aplicas el forma en una sola linea

el codigo completo seria

```
try
{
    String ONFSeguro = @"select DATEADD(year,1, InitVigencia) as fecha1 
                        from DATOSSEGURO 
                        where Poliza= @poliza";
    using(SqlCommand OpFeSeguro = new SqlCommand(ONFSeguro, MenuInicio.conexion))
    {
        OpFeSeguro.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poliza", TBPoliza.Text);

        var Leer = OpFeSeguro.ExecuteReader();
        if(Leer.Read())
        {
            NIVigencia.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(Leer["fecha1"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
        }
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

debes usar siempre parametros, no se concatena en un string los valores